# How to initialize wstring[] with wchar** in D 2.0

Tags: d

In C++, I can initialize a vector<wstring> with a wchar_t** like in this example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cwchar>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int argc;
    wchar_t** const args = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    if (args) {
        const vector<wstring> argv(args, args + argc);
        LocalFree(args);
    }
}
```

However, is there a way to initialize a wstring[] with a wchar** in D 2.0?

I can add the contents of the wchar** to the wstring[] this way:

```
import std.c.windows.windows;
import std.c.wcharh;

extern(Windows) {
    wchar* GetCommandLineW();
    wchar** CommandLineToArgvW(wchar*, int*);
    void* LocalFree(void*);
}

void main() {
    int argc;
    wchar** args = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    if (args) {
        wstring[] argv;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
            wstring temp;
            const size_t len = wcslen(args[i]);
            for (size_t z = 0; z < len; ++z) {
                temp ~= args[i][z];
            }
            argv ~= temp;
        }
        LocalFree(args);
    }
}
```

But, I'd like to find a cleaner, simpler way like the C++ version. (Performance is not an concern)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simpler version using slices:

```
import std.c.windows.windows;
import std.c.wcharh;
import std.conv;

extern(Windows) {
    wchar* GetCommandLineW();
    wchar** CommandLineToArgvW(wchar*, int*);
    void* LocalFree(void*);
}

void main() {
    int argc;
    wchar** args = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    if (args) {
        wstring[] argv = new wstring[argc];
        foreach (i, ref arg; argv)
            arg = to!wstring(args[i][0 .. wcslen(args[i])]);
        LocalFree(args);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use `void main(string[] args)` and convert to args wstring if you really need.

Comment: Will the strings in string[] args be encoded as UTF-8? I'm using CommandLineToArgvW to get wide command line arguments (which could contain all kinds of unicode chars) and then using std.utf.toUTF8() to convert each argument to a string encoded as UTF-8. If string[] args satisfies that, then I'll just use that instead. But, I didnt think it did.

Comment: With that said, if I modify your example and change argv to be a string[] and use std.utf.toUTF8() instead of to!wstring(), I think it produces the result I desire. But, if main(string[] args) really does produce the same utf-8 encoding, I'll definitely use that.

Comment: There is one issue with wcslen() that I didn't mention. If I import std.string, dmd says that std.string.wcslen conflicts with core.stdc.wchar_.wcslen. So, if there's a nice way to do it without wcslen(), that'd be great too.

Comment: Although, I should find a real solution for the wcslen conflict.

Comment: In D string types map to UTF encodings. string = UTF-8, wstring = UTF-16, dstring = UTF-32. D runtime must provide args as properly encoded utf-8 strings, so if you convert command arguments to utf-8, you should just use `void main(string[] args)` for that.

Comment: About name conflicts, D is pedantic about possible identifier hijacking, so if there is a conflict, it can be solved by using full identifier, e.g. `int foo = core.stdc.wchar_.wcslen(yourString);`. Another way to solve this would be renaming functions on import, e.g. `import std.string : wideStringLength = wcslen;`. This statement will import just one function `wcslen` from `std.string` module and rename it to `wideStringLength`. This will resolve name conflict. `wsclen` will call `core.stdc.wchar_.wcslen` and `wideStringLength` will call `std.string.wcslen`.

Comment: Thanks. That should do it. I'll use string[] now, but good to known the other way too. And, thanks for the info on the conflict.

Comment: As far as I know, you should be able to get any unicode code points regardless of whether you're using UTF8 or UTF16 encodings.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
void main(wstring[] args){
//...
}
```

to get the commandline arguments much easier

edit: and the only reason you'd get a char pointer in D is if you are using C functions directly while 90% of the time you shouldn't need to (or should abstract it away)

Comment: wstring[] isn't supported for the main argument.

Comment: It won't compile - function D main parameters must be main() or main(string[] args).